# Finding minimum distance from list of coordinates

Tags: python, for-loop

My understanding is that this should work like this, the code will
start with test list sublist [1,2,3] and move to the points list until
all lines are run and then move back to test list sublist [2,5,2] and
continue.  My goal is to obtain a list which will read like this;
min_dist [[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]] because the minimum distance between
those points are of course the same points.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```py
import math as m        
test = [[1, 2,3], [2, 5,2],[3,6,8]]
points = [[1, 2,3],[2,5,2],[3,6,8]]
distance = []
min_dist = []
for i in test:
    x1 = i[1]
    y1 = i[2]
    print i 
    for j in points:
        x2 = j[1]
        y2 = j[2]
        ID = j[0]
        print j 
        dist = m.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1))
        distance.append([ID,dist])
        min_dist.append(min(distance))
        del distance[:]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in your code:

1. Appending the minimal distance should be outside your `for j in points` loop.
2. `min(distance)` will not return what you expect it to return, because you didn't tell python to look for the second element in the list `distance`.

Here is a working code:

```py
from math import sqrt

test = [[1,2,3], [2,5,2],[3,6,8]]
points = [[1,2,3],[2,5,2],[3,6,8]]

min_dist = []
for i in test:
    distance = []
    x1 = i[1]
    y1 = i[2]
    for j in points:
        x2 = j[1]
        y2 = j[2]
        ID = j[0]
        dist = sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1))
        distance.append([ID, dist])
    min_distance = min(distance, key=lambda l: l[1])
    min_dist.append(min_distance)
print min_dist
```

Output:
`[[1, 0.0], [2, 0.0], [3, 0.0]]`